# why my Handler doesn't work with UI thread

Tags: android

I'm trying to understand how Handler works in a pair with `Looper`, but i have some problem. I need to do some long operation in a back thread and then to send some result in a `textView`.
I get the following error after pressing a button:

> Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button mButton;
TextView mTextView;
ConsumeThread mConsumeThread;

class ConsumeThread extends Thread{
    public Handler mHandler;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();
        mHandler = new Handler(){
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg){
                int arg = msg.what;
                someLongOperation(arg);
            }
        };
        Looper.loop();
    }

    private void someLongOperation(int arg){
        // do some long operation
        arg += 1000;
        mTextView.setText("Operation's code is " +arg); // fatal exception
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_view);
    mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    mConsumeThread = new ConsumeThread();
    mConsumeThread.start();

    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(mConsumeThread.mHandler != null){
                Message msg = mConsumeThread.mHandler.obtainMessage(10);
                mConsumeThread.mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get Main Thread `Handler` You have get `Handler` as follows .
Because:-

> Each Handler instance is associated with a single thread and that thread's message queue. When you create a new Handler, it is bound to the thread / message queue of the thread that is creating it

So you need to get `Handler` which is associated with `MainThread`. For that you can use one of the following:-

1. With Context

   ```
   Handler mainHandler = new Handler(getMainLooper()){
   @Override
   public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
   }
   };
   ```
2. Or Directly with `Looper` even when do not have `Context`

   ```
   Handler mainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()){
   @Override
   public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
   }
   };
   ```

   I assume that you are doing some long running task . So its better if you go with `AsyncTask`.

Comment: Thank you! So my fault was that my handler from ConsumeThread was created and  linked by default to its backthread but not UI-thread. So the decision is to use the Handler's constructor with UI Looper. Right?

Comment: Yeah . That's the case you can use when you are returning from a non UI thread to update the UI . But this type operation i.e your `someLongOperation` you should use `AsyncTask` it already build for that.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void someLongOperation(int arg){
    // do some long operation
    arg =+ 1000;
    mTextView.setText("Operation's code is " +arg); // fatal exception
}
```

//see  here, you are in worker thread, so you can't excess UI toolkit or else exception, so if you want to do something ui related task in worker thread, use runOnUi, see here

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                   textview.setText("");


                }
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't update the UI from another thread. You have to move the code that updates the UI to the UIThread.

Try Using:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       //TextView Update Code
   }
});
```

> Tip: Try to reduce the number of lines of code you put inside this, as then there would be no purpose of using another thread.

Answer (score 0):

*Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views*

You have to do ui related work on the main thread...
So you can do it like this...

```
    private void someLongOperation(int arg){
            // do some long operation
            arg =+ 1000;
            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
            mTextView.setText("Operation's code is " +arg); // fatal exception  
             } 
          });

        }
```